# combination sum coding challenge

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to solve a coding challenge "Combination Sum" (https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/discuss/127208/Simple-Javascript-Solution) and found a solution but I can not understand why `currArr.pop()` inside `if (target >= candidates[i])` is required. I tried to understand by removing it and replacing it but still can not figure it out. Could someone explain why this is necessary to me? Thanks!

```js
var combinationSum = function(candidates, target) {
  candidates.sort((a,b) => a - b);
  const results = [];


  const innerFunction = (currArr, target, index) => {
    
    if (target === 0) {
      results.push(currArr.slice());
      return;
    }

    for (let i = index; i < candidates.length; i++) {

      if (target >= candidates[i]) {
        
        const newTarget = target - candidates[i];
        currArr.push(candidates[i]);
        innerFunction(currArr, newTarget, i);
        currArr.pop();
      
      } else {

        return;

      }
    }

  }


  innerFunction([], target, 0);
  return results;
};

console.log(combinationSum([2,3,6,7], 7));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is called backtracking.
Backtracking is a technique used to build up to a solution to a problem incrementally. These "partial solutions" can be phrased in terms of a sequence of decisions. Once it is determined that a "partial solution" is not viable (i.e. no subsequent decision can convert it into a solution) then the backtracking algorithm retraces its step to the last viable "partial solution" and tries again.

the key point here is that after currArr.push(candidates[i]) flow is recurcion call innerFunction(currArr, newTarget, i); so currArr is constantly growing, at some point if (target === 0) desired result has found and you do deep copy of your currArr with currArr.slice() and now with return, code goes 1 step back to currArr.pop() since this come after innerFunction recursion call.

I hope this could help you -)

Comment: After reading your comment and researching about backtracking, it all makes sense now. You save my day! I really appreciate you.

Comment: I'm glad I helped you